# cannot access apache from internet

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, http

I have a virtual server hosted by Aruba, running CentOS 6.5 (final).
I have a problem with `httpd`. 
I can access the apache page from the server, and I also can reach test page that I create and put in `var/www/html`, but I can not do the same by another computer.

In the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I just add the line: "listen 0.0.0.0:80",
apache is running, I can see it from ps output:

```
root      6107  0.0  0.5 131488  5736 ?        Ss   15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6109  0.0  0.2 130832  2744 ?        S    15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6110  0.0  0.3 131488  3164 ?        S    15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7147  0.0  0.3 131488  3164 ?        S    15:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7148  0.0  0.3 131488  3164 ?        S    15:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7149  0.0  0.3 131488  3164 ?        S    15:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7150  0.0  0.3 131488  3164 ?        S    15:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Here's the output of nmap with the IP address of the server as argument:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
3306/tcp open  mysql
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

The port number 80 looks open...
How can I solve this?

EDIT: here's my iptables-save output:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:312]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:60]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [75:4926]
:INPUT ACCEPT [75:4926]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [53:4095]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [53:4095]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:VZ_FORWARD - [0:0]
:VZ_INPUT - [0:0]
:VZ_OUTPUT - [0:0]
 -A INPUT -j VZ_INPUT 
 -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11444 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8447 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 106 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9008 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -j VZ_FORWARD 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -i lo -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -j VZ_OUTPUT 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32768:65535 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 32768:65535 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 13 15:55:55 2014
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Like i said I cannot access the web server but from localhost!

Comment: stop iptables if running and check in your centos box or open port 80 in iptables.

Comment: also check selinux setenforce 0. and try to access .

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the server locally, but not remotely, then chances are you have a firewall problem.

If you run "`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`" does that resolve the problem?

Comment: I run the command but the situation remain the same!

EDIT: now I see that yuo write "can access the server".
I can access the server, but I can not access the web server (apache) !
Pratical example: telnet server-ip 80 works, but if I try to connect to server-ip/test.html I cannot see the page but from localhost!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your nmap box has access to your apache box. 
Or maybe your apache box is behind a router that does nat and not forward port 80.

You should describe your setup in more detail.
From what you have there the box should be accessible from the internet. If not filtered by a gateway/w/e.

Comment: What others information do you need? I don not think that this is the problem since I also tried with a smartphone with a 3g connection, so by-passing my router/gateway/others.

Comment: do you by chance have a htaccess somewhere restricting access to all but localhost ? 
From what you said you can't access it from anywhere else but now you're saying you can access it from your smartphone ? 
So what's it going to be ? localhost only or localhost + smartphones only ? this does not make sense unless apache filters by ip and or user agent.

Comment: I can access my server from anywhere, but I can NOT access my web server from anywhere but localhost. I only tried with the smartphone, but I did not succede!

Comment: does the client receive an error ? or does the page just hang ? if it receives a http error response - the likes of 404, 403 etc indicate there is a misconfigured apache setting. if the page just hangs it indicates there is a firewall blocking traffic somewhere. are you sure your hypervisor(the machine hosting your virtual server) isn't filtering anything ? perhaps you can check your control panel for ports forwarding or perhaps you have ssh access to the hypervisor and do some checking there. You are running apache in an openvz instance by the looks of it

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if firewall (iptables) blocking the connections ? Try disable iptables and selinux to troubleshoot.

Perform a telnet on server IP on port 80 from the remote PC using which you cannot access apache. Let us know what is the output.

Comment: For questions and clarifications, use comments.

Answer (score 0):

it's not open, not necessarily, it's listening.

that being said, allow it through your firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

should allow incoming traffic to reach ports 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

By default, apache listens to all addresses, but if you specified `listen 0.0.0.0:80`, it will only listen to connection addressed to 0.0.0.0, i.e. local connections.

Comment: You are right. I just changed that line with
    listen 80
But nothing changed :(